# Selecting Parent when Child is hover

Tags: jquery

This is my Html:

```html
<a class='dropdown-button'></a>
<ul class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
</ul>

<a class='dropdown-button'></a>
<ul class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#">forth</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">fifth</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">sixth</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to choose `a` when one of li in ul that is below it is hover. for example select second `a` when `fifth` is hover and select first `a` when `Third` is hover. I cant do this with css, right? How does it work with jquery?

Comment: What do you mean by "choose"? Also - your HTML is not well formed, you are missing enclosing </a> tags.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself to solve this

Comment: can you try this $('ul > li > a').hover(function(){ $(this).closest('a'); });

Comment: @Szab my bad, sorry. I want to style is using css or jquery.

Comment: Please format your html properly

Comment: In the *updated* code (after above comments), the `<a>` is not a *parent*, it's a sibling.

Comment: @AmitKumar didn't work

Comment: @freedomn-m so, how should I select it?

Comment: The title is misleading, as fifth and second a don't have a parent > child relationship. In terms of what you want to achieve it can be done using same class for related elements (or other similar relationship)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the provided html, selecting the higher `a` can be achieved with:

```
$("li>a").on("mouseover", function() { 
    $(this).closest("ul").prev("a").addClass("active"); 
});
```

Working snippet:

```js
$("li>a").on("mouseover", function() { 
    $(this).closest("ul").prev("a").addClass("active"); 
}).on("mouseout", function() {
    $(".dropdown-button").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='dropdown-button'>Section 1</a>
<ul class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
</ul>

<a class='dropdown-button'>Section 2</a>
<ul class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#">forth</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">fifth</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">sixth</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

I should add a **caveat** regarding `.prev("a")` - `.prev` will always select exactly the previous element, so this code could also be `.closest("ul").prev()...`.  It does *not* do the same as `.closest` which continues up the tree to find a matching selector - `.prev(selector)` will get the previous element, *then* apply the selector.  If another element is added between the `a` and the `ul` then this will stop working (and be better achieved using other means, such as a parent grouping).